# Angular code not showing the results in browser

Tags: javascript, angular, web, frameworks

Below is my code. I want to print full names with the help of first and last names, but my code isn't showing anything in the browser. It appears blank. Please suggest any corrections!

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "names",

template: 
`<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<ul>
<li>{{namesList[0]}}</li>
<li>{{namesList[1]}}</li>
<li>{{namesList[2]}}</li>
<li>{{namesList[3]}}</li>
</ul>`

})


export class Comp1Component {
    title = "Hello!";
    namesList:string[];
    firstNames: string[] = ["Harry","Hermione","Ron","Draco"];
    lastNames:string[] = ["Potter","Granger","Weasley","Malfoy"];

    constructor() {
        for(let i =0;i<4;i++) {
            namesList.push(this.firstNames[i]+" "+this.lastNames[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile. Read and fix the compilation error. It probably says something like "No variable namesList defined. Did you mean this.namesList?".

Comment: Just use this.nameList.push in place of nameList.push and assign namesList with an array namesList:string[] = [];

Comment: perfect solution from @surjeet

Comment: Thanks, @Akki. Please do up to my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Initialize** `nameList` as an array first, in order to push elements to it

```
namesList:string[] = [];
```

> **Use** `this` to refer to `nameList` inside constructor

```
constructor() {
    for(let i =0;i<4;i++) {
        this.namesList.push(this.firstNames[i]+" "+this.lastNames[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter can you please explain the wrong part or your reason to downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) in template like this

> html component

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let v of firstNames; let i =index;">
<li>{{v}} {{lastNames[i]}}</li>
</ul>
```

You can see here with working **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tue5al)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array

```
namesList:string[]=[];
```

and use **`this.namesList`** inside the constructor

```
constructor() {
        for(let i =0;i<4;i++) {
           this.namesList.push(this.firstNames[i]+" "+this.lastNames[i]);
        }
    }
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h254mz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.namesList.push` instead of `namesList.push` and need to initialize it with a blank array.

**Here is the updated code. Just copy paste it.**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "names",

template: 
`<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<ul>
<li>{{namesList[0]}}</li>
<li>{{namesList[1]}}</li>
<li>{{namesList[2]}}</li>
<li>{{namesList[3]}}</li>
</ul>`

})


export class Comp1Component {
    title = "Hello!";
    namesList:string[] = [];
    firstNames: string[] = ["Harry","Hermione","Ron","Draco"];
    lastNames:string[] = ["Potter","Granger","Weasley","Malfoy"];

    constructor() {
        for(let i =0;i<4;i++) {
            this.namesList.push(this.firstNames[i]+" "+this.lastNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Find the Demo here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmt7uy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @faceturn. Hey man, I described properly regarding what I have changed.